# Nav Bar hidding issue in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, tabbar

i'm making an app in which i'm using tab bar controller. On the first VC of tab bar I have used XLPagerTabBarStrip lib which has two child vc. Now when i run the app it does not show me the nav bar. I have given the color also and placed two bar button item. Still it isn't showing me the nav bar, How can i show the nav bar?
My code for calling tab bar is this,

```
let first = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"TabBarVC") as! TabBarVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(first, animated: true)
```

This is my UI,
[image]